# how to reset values of select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 different dropdowns which are all connected to each other. in the second drop-down options appear based on the selection in the first one...and so on

let's say I select that I have books and movies in the first one.

If I select books ---> the song of ice and fire and a clash of kings appear
if I select movies ---> Django Unchained, pulp fiction appear... etc

However, if a user makes "mistake" of choosing the wrong book (let's say the song of ice and fire) and goes back to books ---> the same book is still appearing in the select dropdown.

What I want to do, is "reset" or the clear result of the previously chosen section.

I've tried doing this:

```
document.getElementById('books').value = "";
```

but it completely deletes the placeholder of the second dropdown. I want the placeholder to be back to option 0 ---> choose a book

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qvshLcd/3/)

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: So set the value to that first option.

Comment: The `option`(s) which you don't wan't, set their css property(`display: none;`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want change the selected option back to default one. To do so, you can do the following:

`document.getElementById('books').selectedIndex = 0;`

This is just a basic example, where the selected option is switched back to the first one. To do somewhat more advance reset, you could add `data-default-index` attribute to the rendered select and use that value to reset it back. This way you could use a non-first element as a default one.

Cheers.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help! If one of these answer helped you, please consider marking it as `accepted`.

Comment: yeh it definitely did! i will also research data-default-index. And yes already tried, but i need to wait 5 more mins before accepting

Answer (score 1):

Set the [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) to -1 to reset it so no option is selected or to 0 to set it to the first option in the list.

```js
var clk = function() {
  var index = this.dataset.index;
  document.querySelector("#s").selectedIndex = index;
};

document.querySelector("#b1").addEventListener("click",  clk);
document.querySelector("#b2").addEventListener("click",  clk);
```

```html
<select id="s">
  <option>1 Foo</option>
  <option>2 Foo</option>
  <option>3 Foo</option>
  <option>4 Foo</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="b1" data-index="-1">Change No Selection</button>
  <button type="button" id="b2" data-index="0">Change First Selection</button>
```